# Why would IBM Connections Mail load the HTML version rather than the Embedded Experience version of an email?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am going through the ACME Airlines demo and everything seems to be working fine except that the email sent to the approver for the person booking the flight is rendered using the HTML part rather than the Embedded Experience.

This is what I am getting:

[image: IBM Connections Mail]

MIME Message Information:

```
Received: from 192.168.0.64 ([192.168.0.64])
by dominoww.demos.ibm.com (Lotus Domino Release 8.5.3)
with ESMTP id 2012121210521758-3 ;
Wed, 12 Dec 2012 10:52:17 -0500 
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 09:52:19 -0600 (CST)
From: wpadmin@demos.ibm.com
To: gbandini@demos.ibm.com
Cc: lsuarez@demos.ibm.com
Message-ID: <1781867189.1.1355327539212.JavaMail.wpadmin@demos.ibm.com>
Subject: Travel Request For Lucille Suarez
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MIMETrack: Itemize by SMTP Server on domino/ibm(Release 8.5.3|September 15, 2011) at
12/12/2012 10:52:17 AM,
Serialize by Notes Server on domino/ibm(Release 8.5.3|September 15, 2011) at
12/12/2012 11:06:04 AM,
Serialize complete at 12/12/2012 11:06:04 AM
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_168610966.1355327539158"

------=_Part_0_168610966.1355327539158
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Please approve the travel request for Lucille Suarez at http://acmeairlines.com:8080/acme.social.sample.webapp/js/../
------=_Part_0_168610966.1355327539158
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

Please approve the travel request for Lucille Suarez at <a href="http://acmeairlines.com:8080/acme.social.sample.webapp/js/../">Acme Air</a>.
------=_Part_0_168610966.1355327539158
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: application/embed+json

{"gadget":"http:\/\/acmeairlines.com:8080\/acme.social.sample.webapp\/js\/..\/gadgets\/airlines\/airlines.xml","context": {"ApproverId":"gbandini@demos.ibm.com","FlightId":"101","UserId":"lsuarez@demos.ibm.com"}}
------=_Part_0_168610966.1355327539158--
```

What are some things I could check to determine why the Embedded Experience is not loading?

- The gadget.xml has been added via the admin interface
- It works fine in the playground
- It works if I inject it into the Activity Stream
- Widget admin settings: [Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1j8t.jpg) [Screen 2](https://imgur.com/IQOle)
- Console after opening the email in Connections mail:

> [Info] open() is deprecated, use load() method instead.
>   (connectionsww.demos.ibm.com:17) [Warning] ActivityCount could not be
>   resolved with widget:defaultSpinnerController. (socpim:84) [Warning]
>   ActivityCount could not be resolved. (socpim:84)

- Connections can reach the computer running the demos apps
- Connections server has been rebooted and the service restarted several times

Answer (score 1):

Jesse in the entry in the widget catalog for the gadget is the connectionsmail prerequisite checked?

[image]

Comment: I believe it is but will need to verify tomorrow.

Comment: connectionsmail is checked

Comment: Was there anything you needed to change in `opensocial-config.xml` or one of the other Connections config files on the QuickStart image?

Comment: I assume you put cConnections in developer mode as well?  Seems like that is done because it is rendering in the activity stream.  Can you show me all the settings for the gadget in the widget catalog?

Comment: I added links to screen caps to my original question

Comment: Hmmm that all looks correct.  Do you see any errors or warnings in Firebug / console when you open the email?

Comment: are you able to ping acmeairlines.com and get back the expected IP address?   have you considered restarting the server since the changes were made?

Comment: What revisions of Connections 4 (GA, CR1, or CR2?) and Connections Mail (GA or Fix Pack 1) do you have installed

Comment: Not sure - do you know how I can check? This is the demo server image that was uploaded to us by Gopal.

Comment: OK I will research from my side then.

Comment: Jesse the initial information I have is pointing towards the Domino server configuration.  Still trying to validate.

Comment: OK just got the confirmation.  The Domino server you are using is not configured properly.  I don't have an ETA on when that will be fixed, just that they are working on it.